# RxJava2 batch items

Tags: java, rx-java2

I've a continuously  generated log stream i.e a method which get called whenever a new log is available in the system. I don't want to process the log every time it is generated(because  logs are generated every milliseconds or so).

I want to collect logs which are emitted over a period of time let say 5 seconds and then process them in batch.

How can I achieve this using rxjava.

I've tried something like

```
private static void logResults(LogData logData) {
        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<LogData>) e -> {
            e.onNext(logData);
        }).buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<LogData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(List<LogData> logData) {
               System.out.print(logData.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
    }


 /**
    This method get called every time when new log is there
  */
  public static void logGenerated(LogData log) {
     logResults(log);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you recreating the entire flow on each `logResults` call? Have you looked at `PublishSubject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a flow that stays active across multiple calls to `logResults`. The simplest way is to use a static `PublishSubject`:

```
private static final Subject<LogData> subject =
    PublishSubject.<LogData>create(); // .toSerialized();

private static final Disposable logProcessing =
    subject.buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<LogData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<LogData> logData) {
           System.out.print(logData.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    });

private static void logResults(LogData logData) {
    subject.onNext(logData);
}


/**
 * This method get called every time when new log is there
 */
public static void logGenerated(LogData log) {
    logResults(log);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help! I think before `.buffer` it should be `subject.buffer`. If I use the above method It generate some empty block. Also Lets say my log stream ends, it does not emit last ones.

Comment: If I want to do some processing in LogData before calling `subject.onNext(logData);` in ThreadPool how can I do that like code inside `Observable.fromCallable` run in worker thread if we use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadPoolExecutor))` Sorry for asking noob questions

Comment: You need to call `subject.onComplete()` to trigger the last buffer. Add `observeOn().map()` between `subject` and `buffer` to do some processing before the buffering happens.